# Springboot - Cleaning up unused properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on an spring boot application which has a number of dependent jars. Over a period of few months , we have added a number of properties in our property files to satisfy the configuration dependencies in our code and dependent jar files. However when I look at the application.properties file , there are number of unused properties. Typically we add a dependent project and add properties associated with that. After sometime , we remove the dependency but forget to remove the associated properties from the config file.

Is there any way to programatically parse the property file and identify which property is required / not required in a spring boot app?

Comment: Not reliably. What if I loaded a property conditionally?

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. In my case , as long as there is a reference to property irrespective of whether it is conditional or not , it should be present in property file. However if there is no reference to the property in code / dependent jar files , I don't want the property in my application.properties file.

Comment: Sorry Sotirios , I guess what you were suggesting was to fetch all the properties from the beans that are loaded & you had mentioned that it is not a reliable way since there could be some property which could have been loaded conditionally that we may not be able to get via this approach. Is my understanding correct? Is there an alternate approach?